# Problem when import products in CS-Cart with new import

Tags: php, import, product, cs-cart

When I import products with new CS-Cart import, I have problem with fields mapping. In particular dropdown menu show "coming soon..." and not load other entries. I have 600 features fields and CS-Cart load only first 100.

I have modified PHP parameters (for example max execution time etc.) but I don't resolve the problem.

How can I resolve?

I have  a sample image below:

[image: https://imgur.com/pCXzA6w]

Answer (score 0):

The advanced import is still in beta, instead, you should use the depcrecated functionality for now. From version 4.10 and onwards, this functionality will work.